# Access SQL compare is NOT null in Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

My SQL statement needs to compare the data field in table 1 with the data field in table 2. The issue comes in when table 1's data field is empty/null. If I put the isNull() function it returns a bunch of false positives. I tried NOT isNull() but that didn't work either.

What I want is table 1's data field to update with table 2's data if there is no match between the two.

```
UPDATE [NAVAIR Deficiencies] 
INNER JOIN NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp
ON [NAVAIR Deficiencies].[Unique Deficiency Code] = NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp.[Unique Deficiency Code]
SET [NAVAIR Deficiencies].[Technical Data Deficiency] = [NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Technical Data Deficiency]
WHERE (([NAVAIR Deficiencies]![Technical Data Deficiency]<>[NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Technical Data Deficiency]));
```

Comment: This looks very similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960885/how-to-compare-fields-with-null-values-in-access).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit `NULL` comparison.  I'm not sure which column you care about, but something like this:

```
WHERE [NAVAIR Deficiencies]![Technical Data Deficiency] <> [NAVAIR_Deficiencies_Temp]![Technical Data Deficiency] OR
      [NAVAIR Deficiencies]![Technical Data Deficiency] IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed